# How to Retrieve the OEM name of a Symbol mobile device?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to access the system Info on Symbol devices. I am using VB.net. The two things I need are the serial number and the OEM Name of the device. I have been able to get the serial number using

```
myName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName.ToString
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to access the OEM name ie. Symbol WT41N0.

anybody out there know how to access that info. Appreciate it.

Comment: That the code you're using gives you the serial number seems like a coincidence that might easily change out from under you later on.

Comment: That is how I get serial number. I am trying to also get OEM Name.

Comment: I'm don't really know what you are referring to, but is this what you are seeking? [How to obtain a Motorola (Symbol) Mobile Device Serial Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570341/how-to-obtain-a-motorola-symbol-mobile-device-serial-number).

Comment: I can't verify this for .NET as I can't install the SDK without Visual Studio but I have the EMDK for C installed and there is a sample included, SysInfoSample that shows how to obtain the OEM name and various other OEM attributes - I suggest you look at the samples that came with the installer (link should be in the start menu)